# await outside of async function doesn't throw error in console

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, console, google-chrome-devtools

[MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Description):

> Remember, the `await` keyword is only valid inside `async` functions. If you use it outside of an `async` function's body, you will get a `SyntaxError`.

But that's not true.

Try this code in DevTools console, no errors, just result:

```
async function a(val) { return val; }
await a(10) // await is not inside async function
10
```

What's wrong with the code or docs?

Comment: even just a simple `await 10;` prints 10

Comment: or `await Promise.resolve(10)`

Comment: it looks like has been supported since almost one year: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/e8111c396fef38da6654093433b4be93bed01dce

Comment: It works on root level, but you would always write functions in program and you cant  use await without making the function async

Answer (score 9):

MDN docs is right and it explains how it works in JavaScript.

This is just a feature added by the DevTools for making you easier to test async/await code. And it is not a JavaScript feature.

It looks like it has been supported since 11/08/2017 in DevTools:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/e8111c396fef38da6654093433b4be93bed01dce

If you spy the

[ConsoleModel.js](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/e8111c396fef38da6654093433b4be93bed01dce/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/console_model/ConsoleModel.js#129)

at line 129, they have the function for evaluating expressions marked as async:

```
async evaluateCommandInConsole
```

Answer (score 8):

Nothing is wrong.

You've found a [special feature of the DevTools console](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await)! It is there [to make it as easy as possible](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=658558) to experiment with `async`-`await` code in a live environment. You can imagine that any code you enter in the console is wrapped in an `async` function automatically. In fact, as another answer pointed out, this is exactly what happens.

It's important to note that even though this works in the console, it is not a feature of JavaScript.

So, all of your observations are correct and expected! The MDN docs are accurate, because if you try to load a script on a page that uses `await` outside of an `async` function, it will error. On the other hand the DevTools console is designed to make this work (exclusively for developer ergonomics), so your code runs without any errors in the console.

This isn't the only [trick the DevTools console has up its sleeve](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities). In general if you *really* want to test how some code runs on a page, it's best to actually run the script on the page, not in the console.